# How do I set up a cookie-free subdomain when the website is on the naked domain (no "www")?

Tags: performance, no-www, cookie

The website (Wordpress) acts on `http://example.com` and sets cookies.

Will `http://static.example.com` be cookie-free?

Or `http://static.example.com` would be cookie-free only in case if the website acts on `http://www.example.com`?

Asked in another way: if the site acts on `http://example.com`, how to make `http://static.example.com` cookie-free?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create the subdomain static.example.com it will usually be an empty page or location where you can add any content you like. It will not contain wordpress or any cookies as long as you don't install anything there.

However, if you add a wp installation there it will add cookies.

If you don't want cookies you need to add the html/code yourself. Just remember that if you add i.e. Google analytics to your website page(s) you will get cookies as well.

You can (almost) point the subdomain anywhere you like. If that place uses cookies then the subdomain will too.

Comment: it means: not dependently from what happens on another subdomains or on the main domain, one given subdomain remains always cookie-free till there appears any logic, which adds cookies. Correct?

Comment: @Evgeniy that is correct.